# How do properly set up my common C# code so I can access them with a using directive?

Tags: c#

I want to be able organize my most common code elements so that they can be "included" with a using statement similar to

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

I am able to do this to a certain extent, but because of C# rules about namespaces and classes, I am unable to access my stuff directly, I always have to add it to a class and then access it by .item.

For example if I make a C# file named MyStuff.cs as follows:

```
namespace MyStuff
{
  public static class MyClass
  {
      public static int MyCode(...)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
}
```

I have to use it in my other code like this:

```
using MyStuff
...

    int result = MyClass.MyCode(...);
...
```

I would like to be able to just access it like this (without the MyClass):

```
using MyStuff
...

    int result = MyCode(...);
...
```

But I can't get that to work.  I read somewhere that adding the "static" to the class they are in then the dot notation would not be needed, but that does not appear to be true.

Can anybody explain how to do this, or am I stuck with the extra layer?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it with C# 6.0 _using static MyStuff.MyClass_ then you can have a call to _MyCode_ without specifying the static class

Comment: do you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)?

Comment: The "using static MyStuff.MyClass" works.
Thanks Steve (and Crowcoder)!

Comment: _Meant as constructive criticism_... For what it's worth, this will likely confuse a casual reader of your code.  This feature is very recent, and few people will be able to read your code and realize that you are calling the static method of a class that doesn't appear in the expression.  Remember, the code you write will likely hang around your employer's source control system longer than you will be on the payroll - always write code in a way to make the intent of the code obvious to the reader.

Comment: Also, please note that these are `using` *directives*. C# has two completely unrelated features that both use the keyword `using`. One is called a `using` directive (what you show here), and the other is called a `using` statement (which you use to clean up `IDisposable` instances). Using the name of one to refer to the other can only help add to confusion.

Comment: @Flydog57 ... I am fairly new to C#.  An example of how you would clear up the code and make the intent clearer would be nice.  I want my code to be reusable, of course so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... I realized this after I posted the question, but there does not appear to be a way to edit the question after it is posted ... at least that I can find.

Comment: @Cyberclops - there's an edit link at the bottom of your question, just below the tags. Also, if I choose to, I can write `[edit]` in the comments - like this - [edit] - and you're given a second link to do so :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... I updated the question to ask about "using directives" and not "using statement".  Although I have had a log in on Stack overflow for few years, I have not been very active.  I am trying to hone my skills and am therefore bing more active now.  I never noticed the edit link before ... It is pretty small ... thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done.

In order to something to be accessed directly from within a namespace, it has to be an object. Functions cannot be directly put inside a namespace.

You can achieve what you want by making use of extension method by writing an extension method for instances of the 'Object' class (which is more of a hack). But you will still have to invoke it this way, this.MyCode().

Another solution is to have a superclass where you have this function MyCode() and inherit the place where you are going to use MyCode() from there but I am pretty sure that you have already considered something which is as basic as that.